# Meaning and transitivity of ゴミ袋を手に立ち上がる

Tags: words, transitivity

While doing some translating, I stumbled upon this usage of 立ち上がる。

> わたしが**ゴミ袋を手に立ち上がる**と、イツカ君とお姉ちゃんは二人一緒にわたしの所へやって来ました。

It doesn't match up with the definitions I'm familiar with, nor any of the other ones I found in the [dictionary](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%83%BB%E7%AB%8B%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B-320473).

> ①座ったり腰かけたりしていた人が，立つ。 「座席から－・る」
> ③まったく打ちひしがれていた者が，勢いを取り戻す。「破産の憂き目から－・る」 「廃墟の中から－・る」

A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%82%92%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AB%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for ~を手に立ち上がる with over a million hits suggests it's used often enough.

> 総大将は**軍扇を手に立ち上がる**

Could someone elaborate on what's going on and the precise meaning of the word?

Comment: Yet another indication that google hit counts are utterly meaningless: Searching for `"を手に立ち上がる"` yields 100k hits and 210 results if you go to the last page, a search for `"を手に立ち上"` yields only 11 hits...

Comment: By the way, this original context wants to say, she kept her trash bag even she was tumbling. Or she has never given up her trash bag. It makes whole thing a comedy story on purpose.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`A を B に` is a common literary adverbial expression that means *with A in/on B*, literally or figuratively.

In most cases you have a part of body in *B*, as `小銭を手に` *with coins in **hand***, `期待を胸に` *with expectation in **chest*** (= heart), `ドアを背に` *with door in **back*** (= with back against the door), `リュックを(背/肩)に` *with backpack on **shoulder*** etc.

But it's also frequently used with position/moment words in *B*, notably `心配をよそに` *with concern in **elsewhere*** (= much to others' unease), `敵を前に` *with enemy in **front*** (= confronting one's enemy), `その手紙を最後に` *with the letter at the **end*** (= no contact since the letter) etc.

snailboat's analysis isn't wrong, but you can't expect ～に and ～にして to be used interchangeably in real life, because:

> ゴミ袋を手に立ち上がる *to stand up with garbage bag in hand*
> ゴミ袋を手にして立ち上がる *to stand up after grasping the garbage bag*

～にして contains a verb *te-form*, thus always describes two motions occurring in succession, but not concurrently.

Here is [a Japanese thesis](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/110008005817) about the difference between AをBに with and without して. You can also find more examples of this construction, which I didn't cover here.

P.S.
I forgot the most crucial thing. So the 立ち上がる is but an ordinary intransitive verb "to stand up".

Answer (score 10):

して has been omitted from 〜を〜に（して）:

> わたしがゴミ袋を手に**（して）**立ち上がる

して is often omitted from this construction.  In this case, we can tell it's omitted for two reasons:

1. The following verb is intransitive and can't take an を-argument.
2. ゴミ袋を and 手に don't make sense as arguments of 立ち上がる here.

So the key isn't the meaning of the verb, but the ellipsis of する.