# Is usage of を片手に necessary in this paragraph?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

Is it normal to use 買い与えられたポケベルを片手に in this paragraph?:

> 私の二人の姉は当時高校生で、両親から**買い与えられたポケベルを片手に**、高校生活を謳歌しているように私には見えた。

Why not use just 与えられたポケベル or 買い与えられたポケベル. Is it necessary to use を片手に?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20854/5010

Comment: Would the translation be: "My sisters were school students at the time with the pocket bell, that they received from our parents, in her hands hands they seemed to enjoy their school life"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

片手 here is being used idiomatically.
[From here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/41947/meaning/m0u/):

> 二つ以上のことを同時に行うこと

So it doesn't just mean "in one hand" (literally) but implies they are doing two things at the same time.

Comment: So what would be the two things happening at the same time

Comment: @Jon: 1) Holding a ポケベル while 2) Enjoying high school life.