# Unclear sentence: 選を先行する取り組みを本格化させる

Tags: grammar

I have difficulty trying to understand the following sentence:

> 米大統領選などをきっかけに欧米で先行する取り組みを、日本でも本格化させるのが狙い。

Source: http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASK6P62NYK6PUTIL0CS.html

What is the meaning of 選を先行する取り組みを本格化させる here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 《［｛（米大統領選など**を**きっかけ**に**→）欧米で先行する→｝取り組み］を、日本でも本格化させるの》が狙い（だ）。

- 米大統領選 is short for 米国大統領選挙, "US presidential election".
- **XをYに** is a common pattern that means "with X as/in/on Y", "using X as Y".
  [Meaning and transitivity of ゴミ袋を手に立ち上がる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20854/5010)
  So 米大統領選などをきっかけに literally means "with the US president election and such as triggers", which adverbially modifies 先行する.
- 米大統領選などをきっかけに欧米で先行する modifies 取り組み ("movements", "initiatives", etc) as a relative clause.
- 米大統領選などをきっかけに欧米で先行する取り組み is the long noun phrase that works as the object of the verb 本格化させる (lit. "to make it in full progress"). So this 取り組み refers to things like [this one](http://fortune.com/2017/03/22/facebook-fact-checking-tool/).
- 米大統領選などをきっかけに欧米で先行する取り組みを日本でも本格化させるの is the long subject of the main clause of the sentence. The corresponding predicate is 狙い(だ). "... is the purpose."

> Their purpose is to push ahead also in Japan with the (same) movements that precede in Western countries triggered by events such as the US presidential election.

Answer (score 1):

> 米大統領選などをきっかけに欧米で先行する取り組みを、日本でも本格化させるのが狙い。

If you parse the sentence it will become as:

1. 米大統領**選**などを <del>+</del> きっかけに欧米で先行する**取り組みを**、
2. <del>欧米で先行する**取り組みを**、</del>日本でも**本格化させる**
3. のが + 狙い。

米大統領 **選** is the short form of 米大統領 **選挙**

<del>As for the second phrase,</del>
<del>the essence is 取り組みを本格させる,</del>
<del>and</del>
欧米で先行する modifies 取り組み, and 日本でも modifies 本格化させる
The essence of the summary of the first and second phrases is 取り組みを本格させる.

So, you can say the original sentence simply as:
取り組みを、本格化させるのが狙い。

1. 米大統領選などをきっかけに欧米で先行する取り組みを、
   *the initiatives which have been carried out in the West utilizing the US presidential election and others*
2. <del>欧米で先行する取り組みを、</del>日本でも本格化させる
   *to make the initiatives <del>which have been carried out in the West</del> full-scale even in Japan*
3. のが狙い。
   *It is the aim to/that*

As a whole the original sentence is interpreted as:

*It is the aim to make the initiatives which have been carried out in the  West utilizing the US presidential election and others full-scale even in Japan*.

As the conclusion,
"選" is nothing to do with を先行する取り組みを本格化させる.