# About を in 再稼働をてこに収益改善

Tags: particles, particle-を, business-japanese

Can anyone please tell me what does を in 再稼働をてこに収益改善 in the sentence below indicate? I know that を is followed by a verb, but how come in this case it's followed by a noun てこ?

> 広島高裁による四国電力伊方原発３号機（愛媛県、定期検査中）の運転差し止め命令は、再稼働をてこに収益改善を見込んでいた同社にとって想定外の衝撃だ。

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning and transitivity of ゴミ袋を手に立ち上がる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/20854/meaning-and-transitivity-of-%e3%82%b4%e3%83%9f%e8%a2%8b%e3%82%92%e6%89%8b%e3%81%ab%e7%ab%8b%e3%81%a1%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8b) 梃子【てこ】 means lever, a device to shore something up. And here are [related questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20854?sort=hot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that を is followed by a verb..

Not true.  It is often followed by a noun as well.

> 「～～を + てこ + に」

in this context, means:

> "with ~~ as the driving force"

If, however, you insist on "seeing" a verb, try thinking one is implied and left unsaid as in:

> 「～～をてこに（して）」

You should be able to see the verb 「する」 there.

In any case, the phrase means:

> "(anticipating improved profitability) ***with the restart of the nuclear plant (used) as the driving force***"