# 二十歳を[頭]{かしら}に translation

Tags: translation, meaning, kanji

This kanji 頭 what does it mean in this sentence?

> うちには二十歳を頭に、3人の男の子がいる。

I looked up the meaning of かしら and still don't understand the meaning of the whole sentence. Please help translate.

Thanks

Comment: For those wondering why there is an を but no verb (i.e. me), see this link: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/20854/meaning-and-transitivity-of-%e3%82%b4%e3%83%9f%e8%a2%8b%e3%82%92%e6%89%8b%e3%81%ab%e7%ab%8b%e3%81%a1%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「うちには二十歳{はたち}を頭{かしら}に、3人の男の子がいる。」

「かしら」 here means the "***first one on the list***".  In the context of the siblings, it refers to the oldest child.

> "With a 20-year-old (at the top/as the oldest), we have three boys in our family."