# What is the function of を in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-を

> 彼は高齢を理由に社長を辞めたよ。

I found this example sentence in some core flashcards, and the translation says `He gave up the company presidency due to age.` Which makes sense to me, but I don't understand the purpose of the first を.

It seems to be indicating what the reason or cause for quitting is, but then why is 理由に there if を is already showing the reason?

Comment: Very related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/20854/meaning-and-transitivity-of-%e3%82%b4%e3%83%9f%e8%a2%8b%e3%82%92%e6%89%8b%e3%81%ab%e7%ab%8b%e3%81%a1%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8b