# Interpretation of 糧に次から

Tags: reading-comprehension

> 恋愛も勉強もトライ＆エラー。
>
> やってみて失敗し、その教訓を糧に次からまた行動する。
>
> そういう意味では俺も亜子も、今まで恋愛に消極的に生きてきたのはちょっとばかし損だったんじゃないのか。
>
> まあそんな風に周囲から思われたとしても、そこは不思議じゃないかもしれない。

Context: mom giving screwed up love/sex "lesson" to mc and sister. All of this is MC's internal thoughts, but i'm not exactly sure what he's saying

If you try and fail, this sort of lesson, will encourage you try again next time.

糧に次から = encourage to try again?

Also, could someone confirm these sections if you don't mind?

ちょっとばかし  = really really ちょっと? (This idea, for me and ako, mean that halfheartedly trying to get into a relationship up to now will only be of little consequence.)

~から思われた = get a feeling from ~? (anyways, that's what i get from this environment( the lesson?), this is strange isn't it.)

Comment: As a rule, let's not ask more than one thing at a time. Would you mind splitting this?

Comment: it felt cumbersome to repeat the same passage 3 times for such a short section, so i thought this was a better way when there were a few new things concentrated in a few lines. I'm not sure how to split this without obnoxiously posting the same thing 3 times just with a different question for each sentence

Comment: Or maybe you can declare your "main" concern in the title. You're treating three things equally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- What you are seeing is an adverbial expression その教訓**を**糧**に**, [the AをBに construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20854/5010) meaning "using/with A as B". その教訓 refers to the lesson learned from the previous failure. 糧 ("food") refers to something that mentally grows or inspires you. More examples [here](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%B3%A7).
- ちょっとばかし is a more informal version of ちょっとばかり, "just a little", "only a little". It (adverbially) modifies 損だった.
- This 周囲 ("surroundings") means "people around me".
- 不思議じゃないかもしれない is "it may not be strange?" rather than "it's strange isn't it?"

> やってみて失敗し、その教訓を糧に次からまた行動する。
>   People try, fail, and take their next actions in the light of the lessons learned (from the previous failure).
>
> そういう意味では俺も亜子も、今まで恋愛に消極的に生きてきたのはちょっとばかし損だったんじゃないのか。
>   (At least) in this sense, the fact that both Ako and I have lived life in a passive manner towards love up until now...it was a bit of a "loss", wasn't it?
>
> まあそんな風に周囲から思われたとしても、そこは不思議じゃないかもしれない。
>   Well, even if people around me thought like that (i.e., "Ako and MC have lived a bit of a dull life"), that may not be strange.

Comment: ah thanks,  the only thing I'm still unsure of is 次から,  is there an implied 次(の機会/試み/etc) から行動する？

Comment: @charu Yes, it's like how English speakers say "next time, (please do ...)". (BTW, If my English is bad feel free to correct it)

Comment: I guess then, why is から in  used over に(を?) in this this case? (次(の機会/試み/etc) から行動する)

Comment: @charu Literally it's more like "from next time on". Practically, 次に and 次から are almost interchangeable unless you somehow know the next one is your last chance.

Comment: if you don't mind, would "幽霊探知機を胸に....." in this sentence also fall under this usage?    -    だったらオレと一緒に廃屋に突入して幽霊探知機を胸に摩訶不思議アドベンチャーへと旅立とうぜ

Comment: not sure if they're an notification without that woops

Comment: @charu Yes, typical AをBに construction.

Comment: if Bにして/にする doesn't have a dictionary entry, what would be the default way to interpret it? Thanks!