# お父さんの無念を引き継ぎ糧にすることが出来る。 What's the meaning?

Tags: translation, japanese-to-english

> お父さんの無念を引き継ぎ糧にすることが出来る。

I tried to understand what this sentence means, but I am totally confused.
It was related to an assets that left behind, but there was 糧 character which means food or provision, it's really confusing.
Please kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the word 糧 in the dictionary? Not just the meaning of the kanji.

Comment: Related: [Interpretation of 糧に次から](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61086/5010) Is this link enough to you?

Comment: I did check on 糧 on the dictionary, but I can't relate any proper words to translate it.

Comment: What did you find in the dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「お父さんの無念{むねん}を引{ひ}き継{つ}ぎ糧{かて}にすることが出来{でき}る。」

＝

> 「お父さんの無念を引き継ぎ、（それを）糧にすることが出来る。」　 with 「それ」 referring to 「お父さんの無念」.

「糧{かて}」, in this context, roughly means "**food for thought**", "**intellectual nourishment**", etc.  This is a very common usage of the word, too, besides its basic meaning of "burgers and fries" (j/k), the food with real calories.

> "I shall remember my father's regrets so that I will be able to turn them into my food for thought (to live on)."

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. After racking my brains for a full day, I got this kind of sentence that I personally doubt whether it is proper or not: "The thing that I can do is taking over my father’s regret and turning those assets into my benefit." I wonder about this taking over one's regret. So hard to put them into proper sentence.

Comment: @AmandaZhang It's good as long as you can tell that "regret of father" is something like "valuable knowledge" for them to live on / go further.

Answer (score 1):

糧 originally meant food. Now it also means something that makes you grow.

> お父さんの無念を引き継ぎ糧にすることが出来る。

In this sentence お父さんの無念 is 糧. Trying to do what your father wasn’t able to do, you can grow.

Comment: Thank you for your kind input, I am able to understand it a bit, just hard to put them into a proper sentence,