# "に(して)" and the "for (purpose) に" clarification

Tags: particle-に

> とりあえず目覚ましにシャワーだけ浴びて、さっさとメシの準備をしよう。

- speaker has already gotten outa bed

に（して）anyways, i'm gonna (fully) wake up, and just take a shower,...

(purpose) に anyways, I'm just taking a shower so i can (fully) wake up...

[the AをBに construction in question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/20854/meaning-and-transitivity-of-%E3%82%B4%E3%83%9F%E8%A2%8B%E3%82%92%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AB%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B)

Is に（して）strictly only for that construction and nothing else?

Otherwise is there a implied とりあえず目覚ましに(行って)シャワーだけ浴びて to satisfy the movement verb requirement for the "in order to do something に"?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The particle に indicates purpose. (It's not にして.) [目覚]{めざ}まし here is a noun that means [眠気]{ねむけ}[覚]{ざ}まし, "shaking off one's sleepiness". I think とりあえず is more like "First (of all)," and modifies シャワーだけ浴びて, not 目覚ましに.

> とりあえず（目覚ましに）シャワーだけ浴びて、

*Lit.* "First of all, for (the purpose of) shaking off my sleepiness, I'll just take a shower and..."
→ "First of all I'll just take a shower to shake off my sleepiness and..."

Comment: does that mean the "for the purpose of に "  does not require a movement verb?

Comment: You must be talking about the structure 「XXに行く」「XXに来る」 where you use 動詞連用形 or 動作性名詞, eg 見に行く, 買い物に行く. Here, 目覚まし is an established noun, so you can attach a normal verb (phrase) to 目覚ましに, 眠気覚ましに, eg 眠気覚ましにコーヒーを飲む

Comment: Can you expand on what an "established noun" means? 目覚まし is also the stem of 目覚ます, which would fall under [this](https://djtarchive.neocities.org/bunpou/full_day.html#%E3%8A%A6%E3%81%AB(5)) usage, Does this mean that any ます-stem that is also considered a noun does not need to be followed with a movement verb for に to have the "for the purpose of" meaning? Or can any noun have that distinction?

Comment: `目覚まし is also the stem of 目覚ます` -- Hmm.. I don't think we use a verb 目覚ます... We say 目**を**覚ます. So we consider 目覚まし as a noun..

Comment: Could it be viewed as 目覚まし(のため)に..., instead? Are both  地球温暖化に...~  vs 地球温暖化のために...~ actually equivalent?

Comment: You can understand it as 目覚ましのために, but 目覚ましに or 目を覚ますために would sound more natural. I can't think of an example using 地球温暖化に to mean 地球温暖化のために. I think it depends on the noun: You can say 気晴らしに、気分転換に、腹ごなしに、酔い覚ましに...

Comment: One more thing if you don't mind, in sentences like this : "にっこりと首をかしげての微笑に (the girl's actions)、俺の胸の奥がズクンと高鳴った。" , what is the best to interpret it?  It seems to imply causation, but that's not a definition. Thank you!

Comment: The に shows `感覚や感情が生じるきっかけ` (明鏡国語辞典). So it's a causation/trigger of a sensation/emotion/feeling. Some examples of this に: 「突然の知らせに驚く」「物語に感動する」「人間関係に悩む」