# Meaning of 境 in その日を境に

Tags: meaning

その日を境に

Why does this mean 'On that day',
does 境 mean something other then 'boundary'/'area' in this sentence?

Comment: In this sentence? You seem to have forgotten to include the sentence.

Comment: That was all there was to it

Comment: I'm guessing it means 'from that day' rather than 'on that day'. Literally "with that day as a watershed". But that really is just a logical guess. I've never seen it before. If you're not familiar with the AをBに construction then try this link: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/20854/meaning-and-transitivity-of-%e3%82%b4%e3%83%9f%e8%a2%8b%e3%82%92%e6%89%8b%e3%81%ab%e7%ab%8b%e3%81%a1%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「その日を境{さかい}に」

「境」 in this phrase means a "**turning point**" where something changed.

What it is that changed must be explained (or at least implied) in the context before this phrase appears.

> "Ever since that day..."