# に without a verb in a sentence

Tags: sentence

睨みあうサラスとユキを尻目**に**、平松がハンカチを差し出してくれた

Why isn't there a verb in going with the に in the sentence above? In fact, what does the first sentence even mean? (since there is not verb). Is the 差し出し verb shared between the sentences?

Comment: I feel sure this post is related, but I still can't make it work: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/20854/meaning-and-transitivity-of-%e3%82%b4%e3%83%9f%e8%a2%8b%e3%82%92%e6%89%8b%e3%81%ab%e7%ab%8b%e3%81%a1%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8b

Comment: @user3856370 Cheers. Sounds like it answered the question

Comment: What do you think it means then? I can make guesses, but I'm not confident.

Comment: Literally, With side vision looking at quarelling saras and yuki, hiramatsu handed out a hankerchief to me と思います

Comment: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%ef%bd%9e%e3%82%92%e5%b0%bb%e7%9b%ae%e3%81%ab