# Correct interpretation of "桁1個上へ" in following context

Tags: usage, expressions, song-lyrics

Reviewing the lyrics of a song I found a really confusing phrase: "大切片手に桁1個上へ".

As far as I know, "大切片手" is refering to one/a presious hand. Most likely the one the author is in love with, but, the following line "に桁1個上へ" (a digit up?) makes me doubt about what he is really trying to say.

Here's part of the lyrics for some context:

```
だが出来ないならば、忘れ歩みたいネ。
大切片手に桁1個上へと
そこには君がいてこう言う
「改めまして今年もよろしく。」
```

Comment: It doesn't make a complete sense to me either, but (1) in 大切片手, 大切 does not modify 片手. There is a を omitted: 大切を片手に=with precious (thing) in one hand (2) re 桁一個, an interpretation would be *one stage up* (in the relationship between the two)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

桁【けた】 refers to the number of digits in a number. For example, 41200 is 5桁. So 桁1個上 technically refers to "an order of magnitude higher", but I think it's a creative way of "one stage higher" or something here.

大切片手に is 大切**を**片手に, so its literal meaning is not "one precious hand" but "with preciousness in (my) hand" (See: [Meaning and transitivity of ゴミ袋を手に立ち上がる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20854/5010)). Perhaps it means 何かを大切にしながら.